# AngularJS: How to change form state immediately after setting scope variable programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a special developer button on my form, so I don't have to enter the form data every time I am testing the app. The fake button calls the function fakeSubmit() and pre-fills the form.

fakeSubmit simply sets the form value local.code to '000000' and calls the actual submit() function:

```
scope.submit = function () {
    if (scope.requestTicketForm.$invalid) {
        scope.local.showErrorAlert = true;
    }
    else {
        // Send request
        myApi.getTicket(scope.local.code)
            .then(function (data) {
                scope.local.showErrorAlert = false;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                scope.local.showErrorAlert = true;
            });
    }
};

scope.fakeSubmit = function () {
    $log.info('enter fake request click');
    scope.local.code = '000000';
    scope.submit();
};
```

The problem now is that the form `$invalid` property is not updated immediately, so the submit function sets showErrorAlert to true instead of sending the request. I tried adding a `scope.$apply` before calling submit():

```
scope.fakeSubmit = function () {
    $log.info('enter fake request click');
    scope.local.code = '000000';
    scope.$apply();
    scope.submit();
};
```

This works, but it throws the following error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Could you please provide plunker?

Comment: Yes, here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EDfJ2TioUCERHLm41r7U?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Another way of forcing angular to update the scope is to call `$digest`:

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$digest();
}
```

So your code should be:

```
scope.fakeSubmit = function () {
    $log.info('enter fake request click');
    scope.local.code = '000000';

    if(!scope.$$phase) {
        scope.$digest();
    }

    scope.submit();
};
```